# I want a sql query to generate the result like : 1-2,3,4,5

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Dept_Id      E_Id   
1            2
1            3
1            4
1            5
```

I want a output like  :1-2,3,4,5

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you're asking. Explain what you're doing, what you want to achieve, and what you've tried so far and maybe someone can help.

Comment: One employee belongs to multiple departments.so I want all the department id's for a employee separated by comma's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
declare @t table (Dept_Id  char,    E_Id   char) 
insert into @t(Dept_Id ,    E_Id) values
(1,2),
(1,3),
(1,4),
(1,5),
(2,2)

select Dept_Id + '- '+STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.E_Id
                    from @t p
                            where p.Dept_Id=n.Dept_Id         
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') as result

        from @t n group by Dept_Id
```

Comment: Thanks man!! Appreciated